# SSH getting disrupted intermittently

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel

I have Red Hat Linux Enterprise Edition 5 on my box. Recently I started having issues with my SSH service not keeping my connection and randomly disconnecting my clients.

Ping works perfectly fine, except that port 22 is blocked randomly.

Has anyone faced this issue? What is the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely an intervening firewall with a timeout.

You can try telling ssh to keep the connection active by appending to ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 90
```

It could also be intermittent failures of the network. From the sshd_config man page regarding TCPKeepAlive (on by default):

> this means that connections will die if the route is down temporarily, and some people find it annoying.