# Intermittent ssh denial

Tags: ssh, centos

The main server in my network (nothing less...) plays tricks with its ssh connectivity.
It is a CentOS 6.4/64 (runs as KVM-based virtualization host with a dozen VMs on it).

It receives its IP via DHCP with fixed assignment. 
Its /etc/resolv.conf seems just fine, as well as its network co
It would normally work, allowing me to ssh into it and being logged in, I'm able to see the internet, ping external servers etc.

**But intermittently, it will deny ssh access.**

- If pinged from the LAN, it is there; also nmap or opening a socket
  via bash against port 22, it is there.
- Pinged from outside it won't
  respond. Currently open ssh sessions stay connected (but now they
  cannot see the internet nor ping me back).
- The VMs on top of it
  continue working perfectly, no issues there, all have public IPs and
  use bridges as per KVM best practices...(afaik).
- Not a single trace in the log about what can be going wrong with it.
- I consider the network to be healthy.
- Modified the sysctl.conf to set net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=120 to no avail.

Then, all of a sudden, it will come back to life and work as if nothing has happened (but it may take up to 10 may be 20 minutes to reappear... - not good for a critical component...)

No iptables in the way (disabled).

Any hints about how to troubleshoot this ?

(This could be a duplicate of [SSH getting disrupted intermittently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/ssh-getting-disrupted-intermittently) but conditions look somewhat different).

Comment: I'm guessing since your main server gets a DHCP IP that you're using your gateway router as a DHCP server, correct? If so, I would check your router's logs.

Comment: Could it be an IP address conflict? Do the symptoms [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85887/strange-temporary-network-outage-in-linux/86467#86467) seem to match what you're seeing?

Comment: you can add an `ssh -v` make the answer is there. ;D

Comment: To debug this you should inspect the logs of the server if there is anything suspicious such as ethernet link loss or a bridge going haywire. It could be that the bridge starts STP process and blocks all traffic to the server.